# Jersey Test + Grizzly testing a POST method

Tags: java, junit, jersey, grizzly

Assuming I have a REST method which has

```
@Path("/Customers/Add")
@POST
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public JSONResponse addCustomer(Customer customer){
//Post method
}
```

and I have a grizzly container + jersey test.

```
WebResource webResource = client().resource(getBaseURI());
JSONResponse response = webResource
            .path("/Customers/Add")
            .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
            .post(hypo);
```

my own JSONResponse class

```
public class JSONResponse{
private boolean success;
private Customer customer;
public JSONResponse(){}
//getters and setters 
}
```

How do i write the response for a POST REST method?

Comment: Assuming hypo is a object of type Customer

Comment: What is the fully qualified name for JSONResponse?

Comment: It is a class in another package. Does it answer your Q?

Comment: No, what is its full name (including package)?

Comment: The rest is at package com.cutomer.rest and the JSONResponse is at com.Response.retrunRepsonse. I have included the second package as a maven import.

Comment: If you are using eclipse, can you open the JSONResponse class, right-click on it and select 'Copy Qualified Name'. Then paste the contents of that into this post please. Even better, if JSONResponse is your own class, can you post its contents?

Comment: Yes, Its my own class:

Comment: ok, I tried to run it and this is the error I get returned a response status of 415 Unsupported Media Type

Comment: Hey, any cues? @JamesB